# Moving from method to services angular

Tags: angular

I have a function which I use in my app.module.ts as given below

```
providers:[
  ...
  ,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: loadTranslation,
    deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
    multi: true
  }
  ,
  ...
]

...

export function loadTranslation(translate: TranslateService, injector: Injector){
return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
 ...
 })
}
```

My question is how to move loadTranslation method to a separate service and use it in providers with the deps?

Update #1:

Used as given below based on the answer

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (translateService: TranslateInitializationService) => () => translateService.loadTranslation(),
  deps: [TranslateInitializationService,TranslateService,Injector],
  multi: true
},
```

and in the service

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class TranslateInitializationService {

    constructor(public translate: TranslateService, public injector: Injector) { }

    loadTranslation = () => {
        return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {...});
    }
}
```

but getting this error

`ERROR TypeError: o.loadTranslation is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created your service and you called it `TranslateService` as you specified

**app.module.ts**

```
import { TranslateService} from 'path/to/services/translate.service';
...

providers:[
  ...
  ,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (translateService: TranslateService) => () => translateService.loadTranslation(),
    deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
    multi: true
  }
  ,
  ...
]
```

In your service

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
  export class TranslateInitializationService {

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService, public injector: Injector) { }

  loadTranslation(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {...});
  }
}
```

Comment: The `Injector` should not be necessary.

Comment: Not sure about this, he uses a parameter of this type in the function.

Comment: I need that parameter to load the translation. and also updated my question. please check

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan I have edited following your edit

Comment: The app is running, but now the problem is, code which is inside loadTranslation is not getting executed.

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan I have changed `return () => ` to simple `return` is it better ? If it is not working try `let promise = new Promise ...` then `return promise`

Comment: may I know why the arrow function didn't worked? and the above method worked?

Comment: For the function, it is not how we declare it so Angular doesn't recognize it as function, for the return method I am not sure but I think it's because you are trying return a creation of function, so you return it but you don't use it. But I am not sure :/